# Do I need to optimize boolean expressions in Elasticsearch filters?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Assume I have a complex boolean expression in Elasticsearch filter (Actually I have this: given N conditions, the result is true if M of them evaluate to true, false otherwise).

Is there any sense in optimizing my filter to minimize number of checking values participating in query? How Elasticsearch does evaluate "or", "and" and "bool" filters?

Well, I can just have a simple KNF or DNF expression. E.g. for (I have 3 conditions of 4 to match):

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "and": [
        cond1,
        cond2,
        cond3
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        cond2,
        cond3,
        cond4
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        cond1,
        cond3,
        cond4
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        cond1,
        cond2,
        cond4
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But is there any sense to try optimizing it to have potentially lower number of condX evaluations?

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "and": [
        cond1,
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "and": [
                cond2,
                cond3
              ]
            },
            {
              "and": [
                cond3,
                cond4
              ]
            },
            {
              "and": [
                cond2,
                cond4
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "and": [
            cond2,
            cond3,
            cond4
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Say, the atomic conditions are the term filters.

(The reason I am diving into this is unfortunate absence of support for `minimum_should_match` for `bool filters` in Elasticsearch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bool` filters instead of `and`/`or` filters. If the atomic conditions are term filters, their results are cached and `bool` filters make use of the cached bitsets to compute results quickly unlike `and`/`or` filters. As the term filters are cached, it is fine if you repeat them in your query. The results for a given term filter will be computed only once. Next time the same filter is used (in the same query or a different query), its cached bitset will be used instead.

So what I am saying is, your first version of the query is fine. You don't need to optimize it further.

Read more about it [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/)

Comment: Thanks for great answer!

It looks like:
1. and/or short-circuit the calculation of filter values (i.e. or does not evaluate the rest of inner filters for a document once it encountered the inner filter that does match, concluding the entire or will match)
2. and/or are not BY DEFAULT cached (but if caching explicitly enabled - did it use BitSet's?)
3. and/or do not use bitset caches of inner term filters? (have not figured it out yet!)

Comment: 4. bool filters do use bitset caches of inner term filters
5. bool filters do not short-circuit - i.e. it looks up terms in documents anyway, even if there is already enough data at some moment to figure out that must/should have to match for a given document. But calculating term filters fully and caching them as bitsets allows to combine them freely in the future.

Comment: 6. bool filters are cached by default.
7. It is said that and/or are good if there are many terms combined in a filter (especially with "fielddata" execution mode), especially if there are some strict filters that rule out a big number of documents (or probably if there are different filter combinations each time, and not much reuse of entire filter) - that's understood, they can save e.g. 50% of term lookups in 50% cases. While bool filters are good elsewhere it can use the cached bitsets of inner term filters.

Comment: The structure of my filter will be changing quite often (however many terms/fields will be used a lot). Do the suggestion of using bool instead of and/or apply here?
Actually there are nested objects with "key" and "value" fields, and terms from different subsets are matched to values for different keys.
Another promising mode may be using and/or with "fielddata" execution mode (BTW, do it apply to "term" filter or only to "terms"?).

Comment: @AlexeyTigarev Just want to clarify that bool filters itself are not cached, term filters are cached. Bool filters only make use of the cached bitsets. Hence if the structure of your filter will be changing quite often but terms will be reused, the recommendation is to use bool filters.